# Trying to write a POST method for API, I cannot get result on "Postman"

Tags: c#, .net, postman

```
public Kullanicilarr Post([FromBody]Kullanicilarr values )
{
    SmsEntities db = new SmsEntities();
    db.Kullanicilarr.Add(value);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return value;
}
```

My SQL table columns are like this:

```
Kullaniciadi | Telefonno | GrupID
```

Also I am trying to post datas from "postman" like that:

```
{"Kullaniciadi":"jason","Telefonno":"545454","GrupID":"5"}
```

The error is: `db.Kullanicilarr.Add(value); -> : "Value cannot be null, Paramater name: Entity"`

[image]

Comment: seems that you are sending the value as a null object.

Comment: Check if request content type is set to `application/json` in postman.

Comment: Put a debug point at `[FromBody]Kullanicilarr values )` and check if you get value there, if **NO** then show us the Postman request.

Comment: checked, content type is already set to `application/json`

Comment: @Div , i don't know how to put debug point, can you explain to me ?

Comment: @Div breakpoint gives value=null

Comment: @Div: oh.. i am blind i guess. Thank you for answers, its solved. :)

Comment: @Bysalyanman, Glad your issue is resolved. I have added the answer. Feel free to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request body you're passing is invalid JSON. The valid request body is

```
{
    "Kullaniciadi": "jason",
    "Telefonno": "545454",
    "GrupID": "5"
}
```

Not

```
{
    {
        "Kullaniciadi": "jason",
        "Telefonno": "545454",
        "GrupID": "5"
    }
}
```

If you're struggling to find JSON errors, use [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate.